# MySQL Format Date with a Load Data command

Tags: mysql, datetime, load-data-infile

Hello I am trying to load data from a csv file but need to format the date when loading the file.

The date format of my csv file is: 1/1/2008 0:00 
i'd like to format the date and to just the year with the load command

```
load data infile 'C:/mysql/ca_pop_educational_attainment.csv'
into table ca_pop.educational_attainment
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
ignore line 1
set year = STR_TO_DATE(@year,"%Y")
(ea_id, @year, age, educational_attainment, personal_income,pop_count)
```

Comment: So what troubles are you having? The [load data syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing) has `SET` as the last element in the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of columns must come before the `SET` clause. That is, you list the columns or variables to import into, then following that, you can set individual columns.

Also, you need to use STR_TO_DATE() to parse the whole string into a date. Then you can wrap that in another function or expression to extract individual parts like the year.

Something like the following, but I have not tested it:

```
load data infile 'C:/mysql/ca_pop_educational_attainment.csv'
into table ca_pop.educational_attainment
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"'
ignore line 1
(ea_id, @year, age, educational_attainment, personal_income, pop_count)  
set year = YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(@year,'%m/%d/%Y %k:%i'))
```